# Why doesn't fprintf(outputFile,"") work from inside gdb?

Tags: c, file, gdb

When I try to debug a piece of code from inside gdb and the control reaches a `fprintf` statement to an outputFile it doesn't show the output lively in the file and it just shows empty, despite working fine with just a simple run of the program from the terminal.

How do I get my output lively on the outputFile when debugging from inside gdb?

NOTE: I am not talking about gdb precisely I am just asking how to get the output lively in the file on the fly while debugging from gdb.

Comment: Don't explain your code - that's pretty much useless.  Post your code, the output you get, and the output you were expecting.

Comment: By default, streams connected to regular files are block-buffered, so the data you write won't be delivered to the file until (i) you fill up the buffer, (ii) you `fflush()` the stream, or (iii) you cleanly close the file, either via `fclose()` or by normal program termination.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am not talking about any specific code I am talking about the behaviour of gdb in general and any fprintf statement 
the output doesn't show until the program fully terminates or something while I need it to be lively on the fly
so I expected that I don't need to put a piece of code just containing a single fprintf statement to make my point

Comment: The behavior is not particularly associated with `gdb`.  It's just that you are using `gdb` to suspend program execution at a point where you can easily observe the effect of the buffering.

Comment: @JohnBollinger so if i use `fflush()` after each fprintf statement this should be it ?
I am gonna try it now thanks in advance

Comment: @Susano How in the universe is discussing "the behavior of gdb in general" useful in any way [when the PDF user manual for gdb is 890 pages](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.pdf)???  This isn't a discussion site...

Comment: Call `setbuf(outputFile, 0)` once (you can do it in gdb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to [stream buffering](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Stream-Buffering.html):

> Characters that are written to a stream are normally accumulated and transmitted asynchronously to the file in a block, instead of appearing as soon as they are output by the application program. Similarly, streams often retrieve input from the host environment in blocks rather than on a character-by-character basis. This is called buffering.

Try out this example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("foo.txt", "w");
    printf("Break here and go line by line.");
    fprintf(f, "Bar\n");
    printf("Nothing in foo.txt yet.");
    fflush(f);
    printf("Buffer has been written to foo.txt now.");
    fprintf(f, "Baz\n");
    printf("Baz is still only in the buffer.");
    fclose(f);
    printf("The buffer was written to the file before closing.");
}
```

Comment: This answer correctly explains _why_ there is no output, but doesn't answer the "how can I" question at all. There _is_ a much better answer than sprinkling `fflush()` all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get my output lively on the outputFile when debugging from inside gdb?

Do this:

```
(gdb) call fflush(0)
```

This will cause the program being debugged to flush all of its output streams.

Comment: I did that after being answered by @stfwn answer so thanks but just for adding my gdb asked for a return type cast while doing so. 

so the more complete answer should be (int) fflush(fd)